# Bootstrap one selected triggered tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#part1" role="tab">Part 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part2" role="tab">Part 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part3" role="tab">Part 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="part1" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 1</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part2" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 2</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part3" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 3</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio></div>
    </div>
```

How can i close||refresh the previous `tab` to stop the `BGM` from playing when i switch to other `tab`? to be more clear, If i started the BGM from `part1` tab then clicked on `part2` tab, The music from `part1` would still be working, I want to refresh all the tab like if it wasn't working at all, Only one selected tab to work.

Comment: you want to stop playing audio file of previously active tab after selecting another tab, correct?

Comment: Yes, But i maybe put some GIFs and Videos and Galleries, So it would be better if when i switch to other Tab it doesn't take performance in background.

Comment: Bootstrap provide callback event of tab change, but you need to perform audio, video stop at by your own code.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Can you give me a full example please, As answer if possible, And isn't it possible to just refresh the previous tab? Refreshing would fix the problem.

Comment: no, refresh previous tab is not possible, adding callback event code of bootstrap as answer.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Well, put in answer please to pick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look over JS, I've added tab change event. Also you can compare tab target to perform some specific operations for specific tab.

You need to add code for video, audio pause event under event.

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
    //alert('event') 
    /* something like this to pause audio or video */
    $('video').trigger('pause');
    $('audio').trigger("pause");
    if ((target == '#part2')) {
        //alert('ok');
    } else {
        //alert('not ok');
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#part1" role="tab">Part 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part2" role="tab">Part 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part3" role="tab">Part 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="part1" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 1</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part2" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 2</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part3" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 3</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't think that works as intended, the audio still playing

Comment: I told you, you need to add code for audio & video file pause.

Comment: @CaliburVictorious, audio file pause is done, I've changed my code script in answer, Please have look

Comment: Now it works perfectly, Would it be better if i used embed or iframe? would that make it possible to refresh the code?

Comment: Sorry, what you need to do with iframe? can you explain?

Comment: instead of uploading the audio or video by myself, i use youtube or souldcloud, i think that would make it faster.